# Which variables do I need to export with Strongarm?

Tags: 7, theming, features

I have a theme based on adaptivetheme, which uses the color selector tool to allow one to edit the theme's color scheme through the UI.

When exporting a feature using the theme, the following variables are available:

- `color_themename_files`
- `color_themename_logo`
- `color_themename_palette` (gives the list of colors)
- `color_themename_stylesheets`

If exporting `color_themename_files`, an array of files like the following is exported:

```
array(
  0 => 'public://color/omtheme-58e01b40/bullet-round.png',
  1 => 'public://color/omtheme-58e01b40/bullet-sm-arrow-right.png',
  2 => 'public://color/omtheme-58e01b40/bullet-sm-arrow-down.png',
  3 => 'public://color/omtheme-58e01b40/button.gif',
  4 => 'public://color/omtheme-58e01b40/button-o.gif',
);
```

Similarly, `color_themename_logo` gives:

```
array('value' => 'public://color/themename-5cbf1601/logo.png');
```

I know I want to export `color_themename_palette` since that's the list of colors.  Is there any reason to export the other three variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the color module for `variable_get` reveals that `color_themename_stylesheets` is used in function [_color_html_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/function/_color_html_alter/7), which is called by themes that can use the color module. Moreover, the value of that variable is not recreated automatically, when [_color_html_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/function/_color_html_alter/7) is called. This also holds for the other three variables.

So you have to export these variables if you want to have the theme properly colored out of the box. Of course you also have to make sure that the referenced files are in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the paths match up exactly on the other setup.
No if the paths don't.

Ideally you want to avoid putting platform specific options into features/code as they might not be the same across multiple environments.